# How to display related posts from parent category

Tags: php, posts, categories

I am using the following code to display the related posts but it is showing posts for that category only like brand showing brand posts only. What I am looking for is if I select any of the posts under child (brand, advertising, online etc), it should display all posts under marketing so I will not have to assign multiple categories to the posts

- Subject

  - Marketing(3)

    - Brand(1)
    - Advertising(1)
    - Online(1)

```
<?php

$related = get_posts( array( 'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 'numberposts' => 5, 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID) ) );
if( $related ) foreach( $related as $post ) {
setup_postdata($post); ?>
<ul> 
    <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;'); ?>
    </li>
</ul>   

<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this one line:

```
   $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $thiscat_id = $cat_obj->term_id;
    $thiscat = get_category($thiscat_id);
    $chi = array();
    if (!empty($thiscat->parent)) {
        $parentcat = get_category($thiscat->parent);
        $categories_chi=get_categories(
            array( 'parent' => $parentcat->cat_ID )
        );

        foreach ($categories_chi as $key => $value) {
            $chi[] = $value->cat_ID;
        }
        $pare = array($parentcat->term_id);
        $ids = array_merge($pare, $chi);
    } else {
        $ids = array($cat_obj->term_id);
    }

    $related  = get_posts(array( 'category__in' => $ids, 'numberposts' => 10));
```

Comment: Thanks Sonali! I appreciate your willingness to help. Unfortunately, it's not working. Though I have replaced the $related line with your code.

Comment: if you select brand then it should show marketing and brand both posts right?

Comment: Yes, it should show all the posts available in marketing. In this example, you can consider one post for each child. So in marketing, we have 3 posts distributed in 3 children (brand, advert, online). In a nutshell, if I select any child element, it should select all the posts available in it's parent. For example, If I select brand, it should show the posts in advert, and online as related posts because they have common parent Marketing. Currently, it's empty. I am not assigning the direct category of marketing to each of them. Like, choosing the marketing, and brand categories for one post.

Comment: You should try updated code.I have parent category  and two child category ,if i open any child category it shows parent category posts as well as another child category posts.Hope this may help you

Comment: by the way, if I assign both categories like marketing, and brand, then my code was showing the related posts. I am just trying to get rid of this parent category within posts..and keep it as parent only.

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts, Sonali. It is showing one post and it has a different category all together. that post is visible in every category I select, in fact, if i go to that post, same post is showing in related post area.

Comment: Yeah that was my mistake ,just changed in code.

Comment: No Sonali :( related posts area is empty